# How can I change the BASE font size in JavaFX 8 Modena theme that would cascade out?

Tags: css, javafx-8

Currently the Modena theme uses the system default of 12 points for the font size unless the font size has been scaled.

Based on the comments in the CSS file itself:

```
RESIZING FOR DIFFERENT SCREEN DPI
-------------------------------

When the screen DPI changes Windows will use a different font size by default. 
The default is 12px and can change to 15px or 18px depending on user 
preference or screen DPI. On Mac the default is 13px and embedded will depend 
on hardware. To make UI controls scale and be the right proportions for each of 
these font sizes we base the padding (which controls size of control) on the 
font size. This is done using the CSS measurement unit of a "em" where
(1em = font size). The default sizes are based on Windows default of 12px, as
a quick reference here are common px sizes in em units on windows.

Windows 12px -> em units    -> Mac 13px      | 
----------------------------------------
     1px     -> 0.083333em  -> 1.08px ~ 2px
     2px     -> 0.166667em  -> 2.16px ~ 3px
     3px  = 0.25em
     4px  = 0.333333em
     5px  = 0.416667em
     6px  = 0.5em
     7px  = 0.583333em
     8px  = 0.666667em
     9px  = 0.75em
    10px  = 0.833333em
    11px  = 0.916667em
    12px  = 1em
```

Without having to change all the font sizing in the CSS is there an simply property which can set the base font larger or smaller than it's current setting allowing all other spacing, padding, etc to scale?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the CSS?

Comment: You can edit the CSS or apply your own, which I am doing so the response below allows for a single line change and it cascades nicely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define your sizes in terms of `em`, then they will be defined as proportions of the font size. Then having something like

```
.root {
  -fx-font-size: 15pt ;
}
```

in an external stylesheet will change the definition of `1em`, thereby changing the sizes of your padding, etc.

If you want to change the font size dynamically from Java, you can do things like

```
DoubleProperty fontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(12); // font size in pt
root.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.format("-fx-font-size: %.2fpt;", fontSize));
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontSizeTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Some text");
        Region rect = new Region();
        rect.getStyleClass().add("rect");
        VBox vbox = new VBox(label, rect);
        vbox.getStyleClass().add("vbox");

        Slider slider = new Slider(6, 24, 12);


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(vbox, null, null, slider, null);
        BorderPane.setMargin(slider, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(slider, Pos.CENTER);

        root.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.format("-fx-font-size: %.2fpt;", slider.valueProperty()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400) ;
        scene.getStylesheets().add("font-size-test.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

font-size-test.css:

```
.rect {
    -fx-min-width: 1em ;
    -fx-max-width: 1em ;
    -fx-min-height: 1em ;
    -fx-max-height: 1em ;
    -fx-background-color: cornflowerblue ;
}
.vbox {
    -fx-spacing: 1em ;
    -fx-padding: 1.5em ;
}
```

Note how when you move the slider in this example, the sizes all change coordinately: the text size, the size of the rectangle, the spacing between the text and the rectangle, and the padding around the vbox holding the label and the rectangle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this seems to really increase all sizes - even if I set it to 12 which is supposed to be the default, it seems to skew everything off.  But it worked and I can play with it - thanks.

Comment: Ah, I have font set in `pt` there, I guess default is `12px` on windows and `13px` on mac, (note pixels not point); so I think that explains the difference.

Comment: Is there an issue with scaling this way?  If I change the font using -fx-font-size:1.05em; for example, it sets the whole thing, but if I change the system settings, I don't see the windows padding & scaling adjusting correctly.

Comment: Hmm, don't know, and on my Mac I can't test (AFAIK there is no global font size setting in OS X).

Comment: OK the issue was with JDK 1.8_u45.  I upgraded to 1.8u60 and the DPI will scale property.  I tried with setting -fx-font-size:1.75em and resizing the FXML to fit correctly around the new style.  Then I changed the font size at the OS level to 150%, and it all scaled properly.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @James_D so then does every object need to include the .root style class?

Comment: @user9999999 No. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scene).